# Jekyll ruining JSON file. Arrows ("=>") instead of ":"

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, jekyll, liquid

I wanted to make a chopleth with d3.js in a Jekyll draft.

But somehow Jekyll is changing my JSON file from

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features":[{"type":"Feature", "id":"01",
```

to

```
{"type"=>"FeatureCollection", "features"=>[{"type"=>"Feature", "id"=>"01",
```

I wanted jekyll to put my json file inside d3.json() function, like this:

```
d3.json({{site.data.us-states}},  function(json){
svg.selectAll("path") blah blah
```

where us-states is my us-states.json file but heckin Jekyll is putting everywhere =>

Is anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`site` is a [Jekyll global variable](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/).

`site.data` is a Ruby hash containing the data loaded from the YAML files located in the `_data` directory.

`site.data.us-states` is a Ruby hash or array, I assume.

[`d3.json` is a D3 function that **fetches** JSON](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/#json). It does not convert a Ruby hash or array to a JavaScript object.

In Ruby, you convert a hash or array to JSON by calling `to_json` on it.

In JavaScript, you convert a JSON string to an object by calling `JSON.parse`.